# tikzmark error in itemize

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzmark

I am trying to create nodes using `tikzmark` but for some reason it is generating an error, supposedly I am copying from the example of the manual offered by the package.

#### Objective

[image]

```latex
\documentclass[a5paper,twoside,openany]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[11names,table,dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,tikzmark}

%\newcommand{\tikzmark}[3][]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture,baseline] \node [anchor=base,#1](#2) {#3};}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\textcolor{blue}{function} (\tikzmark{a} argument0, \tikzmark{b} argument1, \tikzmark{c} argument2, \tikzmark{d}argument3, \tikzmark{e}argument4 )

\begin{itemize}
    \item \tikzmark{e} Argument0 Note
    \item \tikzmark{f} Argument1 Note
    \item \tikzmark{g} Argument2 Note
    \item \tikzmark{h} Argument3 Note
\end{itemize}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \draw[->] (a) -- (e);
    \draw[->] (b) -- (f);
    \draw[->] (c) -- (g);
    \draw[->] (d) -- (h);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

#### Error

```
>l.97 \tikzmark
              {a}argument0, \tikzmark{b}argument1, \tikzmark{c}argument2, \tikzmark{d}argument3 ...
Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc,
cm, mm, dd, cc, nd, nc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one!
I'll assume that you meant to say pt, for printer's points.
To recover gracefully from this error, it's best to
delete the erroneous units; e.g., type `2' to delete
two letters. (See Chapter 27 of The TeXbook.)

! Argument of \language@active@arg> has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.107   \draw[->]
                 (a) -- (e);
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.

Runaway argument?
! Paragraph ended before \language@active@arg> was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.107   \draw[->]
                 (a) -- (e);
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.

! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\@restorepar ->\def \par 
                         {\@par }
l.107   \draw[->]
                 (a) -- (e);
If you really absolutely need more capacity,
you can ask a wizard to enlarge me.
```

Is there a similar package to create these types of nodes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main issue is with your use of the frame environment. If this is based on an example from the documentation then I suspect it is based on an example that used beamer (the closest example I can find is the one in the historical section of its first use, that isn't a working example but is there as part of its history). As you aren't using beamer, you should remove the frame environment.

There is, then, a second issue with how you are using tikmark. when referring to a location defined using tikzmarks you need to use the `pic cs:mark` syntax.

```
\documentclass[a5paper,twoside,openany]{book}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/604923/86}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[11names,table,dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage[scale=.8]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,tikzmark}

\begin{document}

\noindent\textcolor{blue}{function} (\tikzmarknode{a}{argument0}, \tikzmarknode{b}{argument1}, \tikzmarknode{c}{argument2}, \tikzmarknode{d}{argument3}, \tikzmarknode{e}{argument4})

\vspace*{\baselineskip}

\begin{itemize}
    \item \tikzmark{f} Argument0 Note
    \item \tikzmark{g} Argument1 Note
    \item \tikzmark{h} Argument2 Note
    \item \tikzmark{i} Argument3 Note
    \item \tikzmark{j} Argument4 Note
\end{itemize}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \draw[->] (a.south) -- ++(0,-.2) -| ($(pic cs:f)+(-.7,3pt)$) -- ++(.2,0);
    \draw[->] (b.south) -- ++(0,-.3) -| ($(pic cs:g)+(-.8,3pt)$) -- ++(.3,0);
    \draw[->] (c.south) -- ++(0,-.4) -| ($(pic cs:h)+(-.9,3pt)$) -- ++(.4,0);
    \draw[->] (d.south) -- ++(0,-.5) -| ($(pic cs:i)+(-1,3pt)$) -- ++(.5,0);
    \draw[->] (e.south) -- ++(0,-.6) -| ($(pic cs:j)+(-1.1,3pt)$) -- ++(.6,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

(I added the `geometry` package as the text width wasn't enough for the initial `function` line.)

[image: Annotated function]

Comment: it's true, the frame environment belongs to beamer, and the error still really continues, I guess I'll go for pst-node. Thank you very much for your answer and I will try to use it in another project that I have pending

Comment: @royer The code I posted compiles with no errors on my system, which is TeXLive 2021.  Did you implement all of it or just remove the `frame` environment?  Also, it may be that you have an old TeX distribution which is the cause of the errors.

Comment: I've updated it with code that more matches the end result that you want and put a screenshot to show that it does compile to the correct thing.

Answer (score 5):

For fun, a way to obtain this figure with `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,twoside,openany]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[11names,table,dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}

\textcolor{blue}{function} (\rnode{a}{argument0}, \rnode{b}{argument1}, \rnode{c}{argument2}, \rnode{d}{argument3}, \rnode{e}{argument4})\vskip 8ex

\begin{itemize}
    \item \pnode[0,0.5ex]{f} Argument0 Note
    \item \pnode[0,0.5ex]{g} Argument1 Note
    \item \pnode[0,0.5ex]{h} Argument2 Note
    \item \pnode[0,0.5ex]{i} Argument3 Note
    \item \pnode[0,0.5ex]{j} Argument4 Note
\end{itemize}
\psset{linewidth=0.6pt, linearc=0.08, angleA=-90,angleB=180, nodesepB=0.5\leftmargini}
\foreach \s/\t/\arm in {a/f/1em, b/g/1.5em, c/h/2em, d/i/2.5em, e/j/3em}{\ncangles[ arm=\arm]{\s}{\t}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Always good to see different approaches.

Comment: Interesting, It hurts that said package only works with Xetex, but still it is a sacrifice that I am willing to allow it

Comment: If there were any tricks to use it with pdflatex, I would be more than happy

Comment: Theoretically, there was the `auto-pst-pdf` package and the compiling option `--shell-escape`, but it's been a couple of years I can't make it work. I produced the pdf file with `xelatex --shell-escape` which works fine thanks to `dvipdfmx`.